# ASIHTTPRequest and Invalid URLs

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm trying to be able to catch a misspelled URL on a server.
I already connect to a server and download the URL for a video, however I wan't to make sure that the URL is valid, and there is actually a file at that location.

right now I have

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:path];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:5.0];
[self.queue addOperation:request];
[self.queue go];
```

But `requestWentWrong:` doesn't seem to be called after a timeout, the app does nothing.
Before I put the timeout in, the request would attempt to download a file, and it would save it. So I know the timeout is working, I would just like to be able to display an error when It times out.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered myself.

Used
    [request setDidReceiveResponseHeadersSelector:@selector(requestStart:)];
And then checked the response code using `[request responseStatusCode]`
Which for my particular case I needed `301` (I was checking for mistakes in the URL)